# Will using script integrity checks be an issue with MapBox?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

We are wanting to add integrity tags to our script tags for MapBox.  Does anyone see an issue with doing this. We want our webapp to know that the code being loaded is what we expect, however we don't want to scramble to rebuild if releases get changed without notice.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Will this cause more headaches that it is worth?